# How to iterate over a vector in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have an `Object` with a string vector as one of its attributes in the ftl. I have to use the `if` condition and enter a specfic block only when the vector contains some dynamic variable(available in the ftl)

I have tried to use the condition like

```
<#if (aObject.bVector.contains(dVariable))>
```

But this gives an *invalid reference exception*.
`bVector` is populated with data in java layer but i am not sure if this method can be used or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<#if aObject.bVector?seq_contains('value')>
```

Note than freemarker cannot access members directly: You need to have public accessors.

The aObject class also needs to be marked as public.

Source: [FreeMarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html)

Edit: Make sure aObject.bVector is not null.

Comment: i tried using the above but i am getting the same exception in the stack trace

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression aObject.bVector is undefined on line 138, column 23 in revamp/deposits/lastUsedOptions.ftl.

Comment: Could you please post your aObject class definition ?

Comment: public class aObject
  implements SQLDataType{
private String abc;
private String def;
public Vector<String> bVector;
}

public Vector<String> getbVector()
  {
    return this.bVector;
  }

  public void setbVector(Vector<String> bVector) {
    this.bVector= bVector;
  }

**and other getters and setters

Comment: Just tried. InvalidReferenceException may be caused by a null reference. Make sure bVector holds a reference to an instance of Vector.

Answer (score 1):

it should go like this `<#if aObject.bVector?seq_contains(dVariable?string)></#if>`